# Spark/Databricks data write issue with Cosmos DB with Mongo DB API

Tags: apache-spark, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, azure-databricks

I am trying to write data from Spark (using Databricks) to Mongo DB inside Azure Cosmos DB .I have created one Cosmos DB Account with API as **“Azure Cosmos DB for Mongo DB API”**.

I have created a Database and also a Collection using the Data Explorer of Azure Cosmos DB Account.

While creating the collection I have provided the following details:

[image: Cosmos DB Collection Input]

I entered the following record into the collection

[image: Collection Data input]

I can check the data as well by executing query

[image: Query output]

When I am connecting using Databricks I get the following output with *printSchema*.

[image: printschema output]

When *display(df)* is invoked following details is shown

[image: Display df output]

If I try to to insert one row using Spark Dataframe ,then the inserted data shows null for $t and $v using the following code

```
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.schema._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark._
import com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.spark.config.Config
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val configMap = Map(  
  "Endpoint" -> "https://XXXXXX.documents.azure.com:443/",  
  "Masterkey" -> "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",  
  "Database" -> "db1",  
  "Collection" -> "collection1")  
val config = Config(configMap)  
val data = Seq(Row("B", "US"))
val schema = List(StructField("name", StringType, true),StructField("country", StringType, true))
val writeDF = spark.createDataFrame(
spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data),
StructType(schema)
)
CosmosDBSpark.save(writeDF, config)
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.cosmosDB(config)
```

[image: Data output]

I see new columns are added like the following image for the new record.

[image: New Columns]

**The way the data gets inserted from Data Browser and from Spark are very different .**

Another thing I noticed that after the data is inserted from spark ,the Data browser can not display the collection,rather it gets some error while trying to show the documents.

[image: Data Browser Error]

**I want to know what needs to be done to  insert data properly into Cosmos DB Mongo DB from Spark / Databricks .Please help.**